# Как найти высоту сбалансированного двоичного дерева поиска

Tags: python, бинарное-дерево

Вам дается корневой элемент сбалансированного бинарного (двоичного) дерева поиска root. Определите высоту этого дерева.

Высота - это количество узлов вдоль длиннейшего пути от корня до самого дальнего листа.

Sample Input:
4,0,5

Sample Output:
2

Если кто-то подскажет алгоритм и реализацию его на питоне, то буду очень благодарен! Потому что разобраться по информации в интернете и самостоятельно не получается :(

Пробовал что-то подобное, но всегда выходит "name 'maxDepth' is not defined":

```
# Определение узла бинарного дерева.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None        

class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if root is None:
            return 0
        return 1 + max(maxDepth(self.left), maxDepth(self.right))
```

Comment: У вас maxDepth это метод класса, соответственно и вызывать его надо для конкретного объекта, т.е. `self.maxDepth(...)` хотя если left и right это такие же объекты узла, то видимо `self.left.maxDepth(root)`. И еще не ясно назначение параметра root, который вы проверяете только на существование, но от него ни как не отталкиватесь. Так что может и root.left надо использовать.

Comment: спасибо огромное, Ваш комментарий натолкнул на мысль, и я смог разобраться!!